# Android GridView doesn't load image from url

Tags: android, gridview

In my gridView i want to load images from url for that I have used ImageLoader library,,,, I have used PhotoAdapter.class for set adter to gridview , And I have saved all urls in PhotoGallery.class.

But my gridview shows up blank.

**GalleryViewActivity.class:**

```
public class GalleryViewActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.photoview);
```

initViews();
        }

```
    public void initViews() {
        GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.photoview);
        gridView.setAdapter(new PhotosAdapter(GalleryViewActivity.this,
                (List<PhotoGallery>) gridView));
    }
}
```

**PhotoAdapter.class**

```
public class PhotosAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    class PhotosViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;

        public PhotosViewHolder(View convertView) {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.images_child);
        }

        public void loadImageUrls(ImageLoader imageLoader, String url) {
            imageLoader.displayImage(url, imageView);
        }
    }

    private Activity activity;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private List<PhotoGallery> photoGalleries;

    public PhotosAdapter(Activity activity, List<PhotoGallery> galleries) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.photoGalleries = galleries;
        this.imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return photoGalleries.size();
    }

    @Override
    public PhotoGallery getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return photoGalleries.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
        PhotosViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = View.inflate(activity, R.layout.gallery_child_layout,
                    null);
            viewHolder = new PhotosViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (PhotosViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        PhotoGallery gallery = getItem(position);
        viewHolder.loadImageUrls(imageLoader, gallery.getImageUrl());
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

**PhotoGallery.class:**

```
public class PhotoGallery {
    private String imageUrl;

    public PhotoGallery(int i) {
        int index = i % 3;
        imageUrl = urls[index];
    }
    private String urls[] = {
            "http://mobileapp.certifytechnologies.com/jumeirah/ju_gal_img/gal_1.jpg",
                "http://mobileapp.certifytechnologies.com/jumeirah/ju_gal_img/gal_2.jpg",
                "http://mobileapp.certifytechnologies.com/jumeirah/ju_gal_img/gal_3.jpg",
                "http://mobileapp.certifytechnologies.com/jumeirah/ju_gal_img/gal_4.jpg",
                "http://mobileapp.certifytechnologies.com/jumeirah/ju_gal_img/gal_5.jpg",
                "http://mobileapp.certifytechnologies.com/jumeirah/ju_gal_img/gal_6.jpg",
                "http://mobileapp.certifytechnologies.com/jumeirah/ju_gal_img/gal_7.jpg",
                "http://mobileapp.certifytechnologies.com/jumeirah/ju_gal_img/gal_8.jpg",
                "http://mobileapp.certifytechnologies.com/jumeirah/ju_gal_img/gal_9.jpg",
                "http://mobileapp.certifytechnologies.com/jumeirah/ju_gal_img/gal_10.jpg",
                "http://mobileapp.certifytechnologies.com/jumeirah/ju_gal_img/gal_11.jpg",
                "http://mobileapp.certifytechnologies.com/jumeirah/ju_gal_img/gal_12.jpg",
                "http://mobileapp.certifytechnologies.com/jumeirah/ju_gal_img/gal_13.jpg",
                "http://mobileapp.certifytechnologies.com/jumeirah/ju_gal_img/gal_14.jpg",
                "http://mobileapp.certifytechnologies.com/jumeirah/ju_gal_img/gal_15.jpg",
                "http://mobileapp.certifytechnologies.com/jumeirah/ju_gal_img/gal_16.jpg",
                "http://mobileapp.certifytechnologies.com/jumeirah/ju_gal_img/gal_17.jpg",
                "http://mobileapp.certifytechnologies.com/jumeirah/ju_gal_img/gal_18.jpg",
                "http://mobileapp.certifytechnologies.com/jumeirah/ju_gal_img/gal_19.jpg",
                "http://mobileapp.certifytechnologies.com/jumeirah/ju_gal_img/gal_20.jpg",
                "http://mobileapp.certifytechnologies.com/jumeirah/ju_gal_img/gal_21.jpg",
                "http://mobileapp.certifytechnologies.com/jumeirah/ju_gal_img/gal_22.jpg",
                "http://mobileapp.certifytechnologies.com/jumeirah/ju_gal_img/gal_23.jpg",
                "http://mobileapp.certifytechnologies.com/jumeirah/ju_gal_img/gal_24.jpg" };

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return imageUrl;
    }
}
```

**photoview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/splashscreen"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/photoview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#A3000000"
        android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="15dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**gallery_child_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/images_child"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/splashscreen"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: So much code... We aren't a debugging service.

Answer (score 0):

Have you given Internet permission to the app? In the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xlmns:android...>
 ...
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Yes,I included internet permission

Answer (score 0):

Where is calling initViews() method which is created after onCreate()

Solution :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.photoview);
        initViews();
    }
```

Comment: I forget that ,,But now it shows

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-03 12:48:55.782: E/AndroidRuntime(6400):  at com.example.galleryviews.PhotosAdapter.getCount(PhotosAdapter.java:46)
06-03 12:48:55.782: E/AndroidRuntime(6400):  at android.widget.GridView.setAdapter(GridView.java:184)

Answer (score 0):

In your GalleryViewActivity.class you don't seem to be calling initViews() on your onCreate method, so your Grid is never initialized.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.photoview);
    // Add this one here.
    initViews();
}
```

As an extra suggestion you shouldn't be saving a reference to the main your activity. If you want to inflate layouts you should be using getContext() (or getActivity().getContext()) instead of saving a reference.

This part of the code is completely wrong:

```
gridView.setAdapter(new PhotosAdapter(GalleryViewActivity.this,
            (List<PhotoGallery>) gridView));
```

I suggest you to read the android documentation on [GridView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html) as well as some topics on Java Collections, since you cannot cast a a GridView into a List of objects.
If you don't understand the basics it'll be much harder to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I forget that ,,But now it shows 
 java.lang.NullPointerException  at com.example.galleryviews.PhotosAdapter.getCount(PhotosAdapter.java:46)
 E/AndroidRuntime(6400): at android.widget.GridView.setAdapter(GridView.java:184) –

Comment: I updated my answer on your new problem. You cannot cast a GridView into a List<PhotoGallery>, neither do it while initializing the same gridView, that's why you are getting NullPointerException